# Remove flexible Postfixes to allow AutoMapper to match the properties without ForMember

Tags: c#, automapper

The problem is that we have more than thousend database tables with properties that have a dynamic postfix (e.g. properties like: Name_A1234, Name_B4567, Name_H123). Now we want to use AutoMapper to map this properties to DataModels with properties without this postfixes. The solution with the ForMember function is to time expansive and also produces too much code.

I've tried the following to solve this issue:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name_XY1234 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{

    public string Name_AB1234 { get; set; }
}

public class C
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyNamingConvention : INamingConvention
{

    private readonly Regex _splittingExpression = new Regex(@"\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=_?.*)");

    public string SeparatorCharacter
    {
        get { return string.Empty;  } 
    }

    public System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex SplittingExpression
    {
        get { return _splittingExpression; }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        try
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new MyNamingConvention();
                cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new MyNamingConvention();
            });
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<A, C>();

            var a = new A();
            a.Name_XY1234 = "Test";
            var c = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<C>(a);

            // should be Test...
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(c.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: If the postfix is dynamic, how can you hardcode classes with properties containing a postfix? Also if you strip the postfix and the name is the same for different properties/columns, how will you know what the context is for you will have duplicates?

Comment: In this case dynamic means that the suffix for the properties will be different between database tables. The suffix is a combination between the database table name and the property name. Once defined it is static. The suffix is a relict from our DB2 database and RPG software.We need the suffix to relocate the field there.